# Identify the surface whose equation is given.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a test tomorrow and need help with the following question:

Identify the surface whose equation is given:

> $p=3\sec(\varphi)$

So I know that I can multiply both sides by p to get $p^2=3p\sec(\varphi)$, and then $x^2+y^2+z^2=3 \cdot p \sec(\varphi)$

But I know that $z=pcos(\varphi)$, yet there is a $p\sec(\varphi)$ here, so what would I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

observe that $ \rho = 3 \sec \phi$ is the same thing as $\rho \cos\phi =3 $, or as you have pointed out yourself $z=3$. Hence the surface is the plane $z=3$.

Comment: Wow I have no idea how I didn't see that. Thanks, will accept when I can.